# Retrieve List of TriggeredSends with PHP

Tags: api, soap, php

I have used this code before to retrieve a list of all data extensions using the SOAP API

```
        $client = $this->_initSfApi();
        $request = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
        $object_type = 'DataExtension';
        $request->ObjectType = $object_type;
        $request->Properties = $this->_getPropertyDefinition($object_type);
        $requestMsg = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
        $requestMsg->RetrieveRequest = $request;
        /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
        $results = $client->Retrieve($requestMsg);
```

I would like to do a similar thing for listing TriggeredSend objects, so I can populate a dropdown list instead of requiring customers to type in the internal name of the triggered send they wish to use. I am not having any luck, however, and am hoping someone knows the answer.

Using the above code I have tested with a variety of values for `$object_type`. Below is a list of the resulting error messages.

- `TriggeredSend` -> Error: No view defined for the object type: TriggeredSend
- `TriggeredSends` -> Error: TriggeredSends is not a valid ObjectType.
- `TriggeredSendDefinition` -> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
- `TriggeredSendSummary` -> Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.